# Using css class selectors on a specifc page

Tags: css

I'm trying to position images next to several bullet lists in such a way the global default doesn't achieve so in my style.css file for the child theme I have my selector as

.activities img{
code here;
}

then on the page I'm applying it to I find an img tag make it look like

```
<img class="activities" src"linktoimage.png"/>
```

When I refresh nothing happens to the image. I've tried using ID instead of class and putting the image within a DIV that uses the selector none of which has any effect.

I'm possibly doing it wrong so any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Better ask to ask the experts at Stackoverflow who specialize in CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css

Comment: Ok thanks. I posted here as I thought it might be something to do with the way Wordpress processes the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off-topic, as it's a CSS question, not a WordPress question. That being said.. You need to attach your class to your tag. Use:

```
img.activities {
    /* stuff here */
}
```

Your current CSS selector targets this:

```
<span class="activities">
    <img src="image.png"/>
</span>
```

Comment: I've tried img.activities and it does not work. padding-left:30px; and not one sign of movement.

Comment: Try something drastic, like `display: none !important;`. You could have some other styles overriding you, or if the `<img>` has `display: inline` attached to it, padding probably won't do anything.

Comment: You also need to watch for [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) - but again, very off-topic from WordPress.

Comment: Asked on Stack Overflow. Turns out I was missing a closing } from the previous line of code.